# Record non-retina display in 1080p or more

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, quicktime, recording

I've recently install an OSX Virtual Machine on my computer to record my iPad mini 1 display using QuickTime.

**However**, it seems that the output resolution's limit is my iPad's display size, which is slightly more than 720p (non-retina).

**So my question is**: Is there a way to record a non-retina display at 1080p or more? The content I record is mostly Open-GL 3D graphics, so it should normally be scaled to whatever size you want, right?

I know that machines like Elgato GameCapture exists, but it's way too pricey for me. Is there a possibly free Software that can run my Apple apps on my computer's graphic card? Just like Elgato, but without the external 200$US machine...

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem doesn't have a solution.

Upscaling will never provide more information than is already in the original image. It would merely increase the data load for anyone wanting to watch it, with an actual decrease in the image quality.

Comment: But how does Elgato do this?

Comment: It upscales - it 'fakes' some new pixels in between the existing pixels. it does not 'increase the total resolution' it merely 'adds more data to try smooth things out'

Comment: Oh well, that's bad.... i guess I will need a new iPad then :(